# Dropping object in java

Tags: java

The following code creates one array and one string object.

Now my questions are

1. How many references to those objects exist after the code executes?
2. Why?

Here is my code

```
String[] students = new String[10];
String studentName = "Peter Smith";
students[0] = studentName;
studentName = null;
```

I was thinking the answer is only one object i.e. `students`
But according to [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/QandE/objects-answers.html), `Neither object is eligible for garbage collection`

How should I infer the answer?

Comment: None of these variables are out of scope after these 4 lines so nothing is eligible I guess. In what context is this code executed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How many references to those objects exist after the code executes?

- One reference to a `String[]`, obtainable through the expression `students`.
- One reference to a `String`, obtainable through the expression `students[0]`.

> Why?

Essentially, the answer is that **objects, not variables**, can ever be eligible for garbage collection.

In your case, you have copied a reference of the string (which is an object) into the first slot of the array. Even after you clear (set to `null`) the initial variable, that same object is **still visible from your code, by another name** (and by "name" here I mean "expression", as described above). This is why the string is still not eligible for garbage collection.

---

For comparison, consider your code without the third line:

```
String[] students = new String[10];
String studentName = "Peter Smith";
studentName = null;
```

In this scenario, the string `"Peter Smith"` would indeed be eligible for garbage collection as you'd expect, because it's not obtainable anymore by any expression.

---

*(All the above concern the Java language and leave any possible JVM optimizations aside.)*

Comment: If variables [references ] are not eligible then do they remin in stack forever?

Comment: @loki Local variables are also known as "automatic variables" because their space is reclaimed automatically during the execution flow (when they go out of scope). This is the case in most modern languages because space for these variables is allocated statically. Garbage collection, on the other hand, typically refers to the automatic management of *dynamically* allocated memory.

Comment: @Theodoros Thanks a lot.. your answer is just perfect.. 

Can you provide me your email-id ? (Just to have discussion outside SO) 

Or pm me on snackysrikanth[at]gmail.com   --Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] students = new String[10];
// 1. One object (array of String, 1 reference to it - students)
String studentName = "Peter Smith";
// 2. Two objects (array from (1), string 'Petter Smith'), two references 
// (students from (1), studentName that refers String object )
students[0] = studentName;
// 3. Two objects (the same as (2)), 3 references ( in addition to references (2) 
// first element of students array refers to the same object as studentName
studentName = null;
// Two objects (Array and String "Peter Smith"), two references (one is array, 
// another is students[0] 
// Neither of them can be marked for garbage collection at this point 
// (Array and String "Peter Smith" )
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Here `"Peter Smith` is an object and assigned to `students[0]` so it cannot be garbage collected and `studentName=null`, it points to nothing so no trying garbage collect it.

So, both cannot be garbage collected.

Answer (score 3):

An object can have multiple references, even though you set reference of `studentName` to null the String object is still being referenced by `student[0]`. So the String `"Peter Smith"` can't be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that `students` is an object, but it an object of type String array.  In an array each element of an array can reference other objects, and the first element `students[0]' is referencing the string object containing "Peter Smith" so that object is still being referenced and thus not eligible for garbage collection.  When students goes out of scope and becomes eligible for GC itself then the string object will too.

Answer (score 1):

`students` is instantiated and then altered, so there is no reason for it to be collected because we still have a reference. `studentName` is instantiated, then the reference is assigned to `students`, so when it is dereferenced in the last line, a reference to the object, the string, still exists in the array, that's why nothing is collected by the GC.

Comment: The fact that `students` array is altered later isn't a reason to be alive after that codes executes.

Comment: I never said it was, I am listing what happens to the array, and since nothing involves dereferencing I then conclude that it is not eligible to GC.